# Migrating Oracle DATE columns to TIMESTAMP with timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g, timestamp

Bakground:
I've got a legacy app I'm working on that uses DATE types for most time storage in the database.  I'd like to try update some of these tables so that they can utilize time zones since this is causing problems with users in different areas from where the db is(see *A* below).  This is for Oracle 10g.

Quetions:

1) Can I migrate this "in place."  That is can I convert like so

```
DATE_COL = type:DATE   =>    DATE_COL = type:TIMESTAMP
```

...or will I have to use a different column name?

Keep in mind that data needs to be retained.  If this can be done semi-easily in a migration script it will work for my purposes.

2) Will this type of conversion be backwards compatible?  We likely have some scripts or reports that will hit this table that we may not know about.  We can probably deal with it but I'd like to know what sort of hornet's nest I'm walking into.

3) What pitfalls should I be on the lookout for?

Thanks,

EDIT:
(partly in response to Gary)

I'm fine with a multi-step process.

1) move data to a new Timestamp column (caled TEMP) with some sort of conversion 
2) drop old column (we'll call it MY_DATE)
3) create new timestamp column with the old date column name (MY_DATE)
4) move data to the MY_DATE column 
5) drop TEMP column

*A* Gary also wanted clarification on the specific timezone issue.  I copied my answer from below to keep it more readable.

Basically the data will be accessed from several different areas. We need to be able to convert to/from the local time zone as needed. We also have triggers that use sysdate further complicating things. timestamp with time zone alleviates a lot of this pain.

Oh and thanks for the answers so far.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could just run:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY your_date_column TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
```

But I would recommend adding a TIMESTAMP column to the table, using an UPDATE statement to populate, and drop the original date column if you so choose:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD date_as_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;

UPDATE your_table
   SET date_as_timestamp = CAST(date_column AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
```

The conversion is backwards compatible - you can switch back & forth as you like.

Comment: I guess what I'd like clarified is if I replace the column with a time stamp (like I describe in my update), will reports and queries that use these fields choke on a Timestamp?  (this will be read only)  Could I consider a timestamp to be a subclass of date or are there enough oracle subtleties to make that a very bad assumption?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is a different datatype - reports & queries will have to be reviewed for impact.  It's not that the db will "choke", but that functions/etc are likely not to be flexible on the datatype so they'll have to be updated to suit.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` does not record the time zone which is what the question requires.  You should use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm.  The former stores the date and time zone in the column while the latter stores the date normalized to the database time zone, but translates it to the user session time when the user queries the column.

Comment: Another little hint: If you add a new column and fill it with CAST(...), the current session time zone is used for the conversion. However, if only the data type of the column is changed, the date is interpreted as UTC and the result is usually different.

Comment: Just wanted to point out First ALTER statement will fail with 
ORA-01439 column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

It works fine for date to timestamp promotion but not for date to timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 7):

Simple enough to demonstrate

```
SQL>  create table x (y date);
Table created.
SQL> insert into x select sysdate from dual;
1 row created.
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.
SQL> alter table x modify y timestamp;
Table altered.
SQL> select * from x;

Y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03/NOV/09 12:49:03.000000 PM
SQL> alter table x modify y date;
Table altered.
SQL> select * from x;
Y
---------
03/NOV/09
SQL> alter table x modify y timestamp with time zone;
alter table x modify y timestamp with time zone
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
SQL> alter table x modify y timestamp with local time zone;
Table altered.
SQL> alter table x modify y date;
Table altered.
```

So you can go from date to timestamp (or timestamp with local timezone) and back again, but not for timestamp with time zone (ie where the offset is persisted).
You'd have to add another column, and copy the existing data over (with a default for the appropriate time zone).

"causing problems with users in different areas from where the db is".
Might help to be a bit more specific. Is it sufficient to convert the dates (or timestamps) from the database timezone to the user's timezone when inserted/changed/queried, or do you actually need to persist the fact that the record was created at 3:00pm in a specific timezone.

Comment: "causing problems with users in different areas from where the db is" Basically the data will be accessed from several different areas.  We need to be able to convert to/from the local time zone as needed.  WE also have triggers that use sysdate further complicating things.  timestamp with time zone alleviates a lot of this pain.

Comment: Does timestamp with LOCAL time zone resolve the problem. If so, it is the easiest solution to implement.

Comment: PS. When you subtract one date from another, you get a numeric answer in days. With timestamps, you'd get an INTERVAL datatype. That is one pitfall to look for