# Oracle Time Zone

Tags: oracle

I have a application (java - oracle 11g R2)  which is running on a single time zone. Now it has to be run on multiple time zones. My requirement is, want to store the data in one time zone(say IST) irrespective of login timezones. But wants application to display date and time to user as per the respective Entities time zone. I will not be able to change all the oracle queries already written. Wants to attach user to location and on user login alter (oracle) session of the user to his local time zone.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` is time zone aware. It stores the data in the time zone of the database server. If a user connects from a different time zone, the stored value gets displayed in his local time zone.

To change `DATE` columns, you can use

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY d TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE;
```

The queries can should be inspected, for details see [Migrating Oracle DATE columns to TIMESTAMP with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664627/migrating-oracle-date-columns-to-timestamp-with-timezone).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Oracle DATE type, which stores dates independent of timezone.

Then, note that the Java Date class is also timezone-independent.

Done this way, dates only get timezones when you format them as strings to show them to the client.

I see this question so often that I recently wrote a blog post about it.
See it [here](http://greybeardedgeek.net/2012/11/24/java-dates/).

Comment: Thanks for answering.. finally we have found a way out.                 Attach a time zone to every logged in user.       Alter system to set timezone. Then use current_date instead of sysdate.