# Converting timezones in oracle?

Tags: oracle, timezone

Is there a simple code to convert a given date/time to a diff timezone which should also take into account DST? I have the date time values(in UTC) and the timezone to be converted.

I know this can be done by creating a stored procedure or function but just checking to see if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Oracle DATE columns to TIMESTAMP with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664627/migrating-oracle-date-columns-to-timestamp-with-timezone)

Comment: Yes there is, but you haven't said what time zone you want to convert to, or whether you want this to be part of a query result set or if you're trying to change the data type in a table. Please edit your question to explain further, and include sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- `CAST( date_column AS TIMESTAMP )` to convert a `DATE` data type to a `TIMESTAMP` data type;
- `FROM_TZ( timestamp_column, 'UTC' )` to convert a `TIMESTAMP` data type to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type at the `UTC` time zone.
- `timestamp_with_timezone_column AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/LONDON'` to convert a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type from one time zone to another.

Putting that all together:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1ec59/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( date_time ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2018-08-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: (also using `TO_CHAR` to display the `TIMESTAMP` nicely)

```
SELECT date_time,
       TO_CHAR( FROM_TZ( CAST( date_time AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/LONDON', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' ) AS london_date_time
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1ec59/2/0)**:

```
|            DATE_TIME |                 LONDON_DATE_TIME |
|----------------------|----------------------------------|
| 2018-08-23T00:00:00Z | 2018-08-23T01:00:00.000000+01:00 |
| 2018-08-23T11:20:56Z | 2018-08-23T12:20:56.000000+01:00 |
| 2018-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-12-01T00:00:00.000000+00:00 |
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what i was looking for.